# What are "Aliases" under Open Directory's local node?

Tags: open-directory

If I run `dscl . -readall Aliases` I get the following:

```
dsAttrTypeNative:members: root
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: administrator
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
-
dsAttrTypeNative:members: root
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: dumper
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
-
dsAttrTypeNative:members: postmaster
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: MAILER-AGENT
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
-
dsAttrTypeNative:members: postmaster
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: MAILER-DAEMON
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
-
dsAttrTypeNative:members: root
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: manager
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
-
dsAttrTypeNative:members: root
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: nobody
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
-
dsAttrTypeNative:members: root
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: operator
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
-
dsAttrTypeNative:members: root
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
RecordName: postmaster
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Aliases
```

When are these aliases used? In particular, I'm worried that a nobody user (which is also a real user) is aliased to root.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this database is used to supply [aliases](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html) for the postfix daemon, which can be run independently or by Server.app's Mail Server: `RecordName` redirects to `dsAttrTypeNative:members`.

I traced the origin of the Aliases database to NeXTSTEP's [NetInfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetInfo), e.g. see the [user manual](https://www.levenez.com/NeXTSTEP/netinfo_user_guide.pdf) for NetInfo Editions 4.x.